# inserting values into an sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

there seems to be some problem with the insert statement in my code
it is causing my application to shut down
can anyone tell me Why?

```
    public void insert(String clas,String sub,String name)

 {
    Log.i("inserted","one Record");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,name);

        values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBJECT,sub);
        values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_CLASS, clas );

        // Inserting Row
      database.insert(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
        DBHELPER.close(); // Closing database connection
  }
```

Comment: its entering this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          public void insertFriendList(String clas,String sub,String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase slb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,name);

            values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUBJECT,sub);
            values.put(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.COLUMN_CLASS, clas );
    slb.insert(AttendAppDbOpenHelper.TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    slb.close();
}
```

try this 
hope this may helps you